# Scroll content on overlaying div when underlying image is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div overlaying an image. The top div has some interactively created svg contents. The underlying image has scroll bars. When I scroll the image I am looking to have the overlaying div's contents also scroll accordingly. In other words, any item that is interactively created on the top div should behave like it was created on the image directly. It should have a fixed position with respect to the underlying image and scroll as the image is scrolled.

Following is the what I have:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 680px">
          <img style="max-width: 780px; display: block;"
            src="someimage.png" />

        <div style="display: block; max-width: 780px; top:70px; left:0px; border: solid 1px red; position: absolute">This text should scroll when the image behind is scrolled.</div>

    </div>
```

I am open to using jquery or any other plugins to achieve this behavior. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use image as background of div and type any thing in div will be on top of image

try following

```
<div style="display: block; max-width: 780px; padding-top:70px; left:0px; border: solid 1px red;  background-image: url(someimage.png); height:1200px;">This text should scroll when the image behind is scrolled.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried using the image as background image instead of a separate 'img' element. It does overcome the issue of having the image and the overlaying div as separate entities but it seems to have an issue with generating scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from admoghal, I have tried the following:

```
<div style="width: 900px; height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; display: block; position: absolute;">
   <div class="scales" id="holder" style='left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 1000px; overflow: hidden; display: block; position: relative; max-height: 1000px; max-width: 1200px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url("someimage.png"); background-size: contain;'>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in Firefox but since "background-size" is not a valid attribute in IE, I had to use the backgroundSize plugin from http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/ to make it work in IE. Although, now I have ended up using the RaphaelJS plugin and using its image function for having my image on the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem for an editor I am writing: an overflow:auto div containing an image and an SVG overlay for dynamically annotating the image. Here's what worked for me (the background-image clue from amdoghal pointed me in the right direction - dummy-map.png is the image I'm annotating).

```
<div id="wme_map" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid black; padding:0; overflow: auto;">
    <div id="svg-overlay"  style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; background-image: url(dummy-map.png)">
        <svg width="1920" height="1080">
            <rect x=20 y=20 width=200 height=32 style="stroke:red; fill:none; stroke-width:2;" />
        </svg>
    </div>              
</div>
```